# Add font in fckeditor for copy paste from ms word with hindi font

Tags: php, html, ms-word

I am trying to copy hindi fonts from ms word.which is in MENKA fonts and do not paste properly in my fckeditor.what can be the problem is?and is it posible to solve this problem whith adding that MENKA font into fck editor ,how can i add MENKA FONTS in FCKeditor.

Comment: I'd recommend updating to CK editor while you're at it.http://ckeditor.com/support/faq/fckeditor

Comment: I have to use fckeditor because i also use other font text(gujrati font-TERAFONT-TRILOCHAN) from word and copy paste it in fckeditor thats works perfect but it do not work 
        for hindi font(menka) so now i want solution for this menka font can i add it or i have to change son=mthing in fckeditor to support copy paste for menka font from ms word.